# JQuery .html selector, images not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am trying to create a navigation bar, that when clicked, changed the HTML of a div. I am using Jquery with the .html selector, and it works fine with text. But when I try to put images into the changed text, all of my script stops working. In the code snippet, it works, but the image doesn't show up. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#person").click(function(){
        $("#replacement").html("<h1> About K</h1><p>I like burritos</p>.");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#developer").click(function(){
        $("#replacement").html("<h1> Development</h1><p>I like development and art!</p>.");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#translator").click(function(){
        $("#replacement").html("<h1> Translation</h1><p>I like translating</p>.");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#designer").click(function(){
        $("#replacement").html("<h1> Design</h1><p>I like development and art!</p>.");
    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#person").click(function(){
        $("#software").html("<h1> Base Skills</h1>.");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#translator").click(function(){
        $("#software").html("<img class='softIcon' src='http://blog.lionbridge.com/translation/files/2013/11/Orange-Translate-Button.jpg'>");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#designer").click(function(){
        $("#software").html("<h1> Development  Design Skills</h1>.");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#developer").click(function(){
        $("#software").html("<h1> Development Skills</h1>.");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="person">Person</button>
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-warning" id="developer">Developer</button>
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-info" id="designer">Designer</button>
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-success" id="translator">Translator</button>
</div>

<div id="replacement">
<article class="aboutText"><h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
<p> Text</p></article>
</div>

<div id="software">
<article class="aboutText"><h1>Base Skills</h1>
<p> Text</p></article>
</div>
```

Comment: Close the image tag

Comment: That was actually a typo from my retyping the code. I had deleted it earlier in frustration. Even after closing the tag it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not closing the img tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#translator").click(function(){
        $("#software").html("<img class='softIcon' src='http://blog.lionbridge.com/translation/files/2013/11/Orange-Translate-Button.jpg'"); // >
    });
});
```

#### Tips:

- You don't need to all those `$(document).ready()`. Put all click events into a single one
- Cache `$("#software")`, and `$("#replacement")` by assigning them to a variable to save some memory
- Instead of replacing the content every time a button is clicked, use tabs and switch between them.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $("#person").click(function(){
        $("#replacement").html("<h1> About K</h1><p>I like burritos</p>.");
    });
  
    $("#developer").click(function(){
        $("#replacement").html("<h1> Development</h1><p>I like development and art!</p>.");
    });

    $("#translator").click(function(){
        $("#replacement").html("<h1> Translation</h1><p>I like translating</p>.");
    });

    $("#designer").click(function(){
        $("#replacement").html("<h1> Design</h1><p>I like development and art!</p>.");
    });

    $("#person").click(function(){
        $("#software").html("<h1> Base Skills</h1>.");
    });

    $("#translator").click(function(){
        $("#software").html("<img class='softIcon' src='http://blog.lionbridge.com/translation/files/2013/11/Orange-Translate-Button.jpg'>");
    });

    $("#designer").click(function(){
        $("#software").html("<h1> Development  Design Skills</h1>.");
    });

    $("#developer").click(function(){
        $("#software").html("<h1> Development Skills</h1>.");
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="person">Person</button>
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-warning" id="developer">Developer</button>
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-info" id="designer">Designer</button>
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-success" id="translator">Translator</button>
</div>

<div id="replacement">
<article class="aboutText"><h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
<p> Text</p></article>
</div>

<div id="software">
<article class="aboutText"><h1>Base Skills</h1>
<p> Text</p></article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm actually new to Jquery so I didn't think to wrap it up. When I tried this with my code, I found there was something missing from the script above it, which seems to have caused the issue. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e16r51ow/)

In this below function you code seems to be wrong. your'e missing `/>`

**Before**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#translator").click(function(){
        $("#software").html("<img class='softIcon' src='http://blog.lionbridge.com/translation/files/2013/11/Orange-Translate-Button.jpg'>");
    });
});
```

**After (Working Code)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#translator").click(function(){
        $("#software").html("<img class='softIcon' src='http://blog.lionbridge.com/translation/files/2013/11/Orange-Translate-Button.jpg'/>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to close the `img` tag like so :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#translator").click(function(){
        $("#software").html("<img class='softIcon' src='http://blog.lionbridge.com/translation/files/2013/11/Orange-Translate-Button.jpg'/>");
    });
```

not sure why you use `$(document).ready(function(){` before every function. you could use it at the start of the script and wrap everything else in it...and close it at the end. looks better

also assign  `#software` and `$("#replacement")` to a variable

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var repl = $("#replacement")
        soft = $("#software")
    $("#person").click(function(){
        $(repl).html("<h1> About K</h1><p>I like burritos</p>.");
    });
  



    $("#developer").click(function(){
        $(repl).html("<h1> Development</h1><p>I like development and art!</p>.");
    });



    $("#translator").click(function(){
        $(repl).html("<h1> Translation</h1><p>I like translating</p>.");
    });


    $("#designer").click(function(){
        $(repl).html("<h1> Design</h1><p>I like development and art!</p>.");
    });




    $("#person").click(function(){
        $(soft).html("<h1> Base Skills</h1>.");
    });


    $("#translator").click(function(){
        $(soft).html("<img class='softIcon' src='http://blog.lionbridge.com/translation/files/2013/11/Orange-Translate-Button.jpg'/>");
    });

    $("#designer").click(function(){
        $(soft).html("<h1> Development  Design Skills</h1>.");
    });

    $("#developer").click(function(){
        $(soft).html("<h1> Development Skills</h1>.");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="person">Person</button>
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-warning" id="developer">Developer</button>
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-info" id="designer">Designer</button>
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-success" id="translator">Translator</button>
</div>

<div id="replacement">
<article class="aboutText"><h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
<p> Text</p></article>
</div>

<div id="software">
<article class="aboutText"><h1>Base Skills</h1>
<p> Text</p></article>
</div>
```